# Label, which once clicked changes to optionbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a table, and it has a label in one of its containers, what I want is so when the user clicks on that label it will turn into a optionbox with options and the user can select one then when he clicks out it will switch to the label he chose.

I am assuming this can be done in Javascript.

Comment: "I am assuming this can be done in Javascript as PHP is clientside." -- huh?

Comment: Ah OK then :-)  I figured that's what you meant but just wanted to check.

Comment: Well, Generated serverside and rendered clientside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/fECsH/1/)? It's just a quick-and-dirty JavaScript implementation, so if you have other, specific requirements, feel free to add to the question.

Comment: YES! Exactly that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in JavaScript.

[Here is a small, self-contained example](http://jsfiddle.net/GzexB/) that shows the answer using the javascript framework [jQuery](http://jquery.com).  If you are going to be heavily into Javascript on your page, I recommend using a framework.

[Here is that same example](http://jsfiddle.net/w99V8/1/) using no Javascript frameworks.

Both examples rely on providing a class to a div containing the label/select indicating whether it is currently a label or a select.  Both use a click handler on the whole document and a click handler on the label/select.

I highly recommend you digging into events and handlers in Javascript as well as the Document Object Model (DOM) if you already haven't to understand how this works.